# Any oauth2 library for ColdFusiion?

Tags: coldfusion, oauth-2.0, coldfusion-11

I have designed a Restful component using Coldfusion 11. Now I need to think of securing this REST service.After searching for sometime
I found HTTPS + oauth2 is the best combination for securing REST service.

In the official [oauth2](http://oauth.net/2/) page,  We have libraries for different languages. But there is nothing listed for ColdFusion.
Any one having any kind of knowledge if we have a library for oauth2 in ColdFusion?

Comment: Any java library is also a CF library since CF is just a wrapper around Java application server of choice. You could add the jar files and then user cfobject/createobject to access them.

Comment: @xpa1492: Any idea Can I use this one https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [this](https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/oauth2). This CF script is built by [Matt Gifford](https://github.com/coldfumonkeh) 3 years ago, so you might want to take a look and update some code. But as far as i believe, it was designed to work on CF9 and CF10, so it will work on CF11 as well.

 Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I do not think this is the complete library.

Comment: @user3427540, if this is not what you are looking for, then sadly there is none in ColdFusion.

Comment: @user3427540, There is [another one](https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/monkehTweets/tree/4b7de2cf0f19e5c1c4f649e28329dd40c37d6d6c/com/coldfumonkeh/oauth) but it is on oAuth , not on oAuth2.

Comment: RiaForge has several listed - including one that's recent and not by Matt. http://www.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=page.search#oAuth

Comment: @MarkAKruger, I have already checked that. Only one of them is what our OP required but that is also based on OAuth1.0, not on oAuth2. From what i understand is that OP want CF implementation of oAuth protocol, not that he wants to use/consume oAuth. If i am mistaken, then there are many as you pointed out.

Comment: Got it. - this is something we need to dev and publish out there I think. A glaring need.

Comment: @MarkAKruger, Yes indeed. I hope it will happen soon though.

Comment: @MarkAKruger, As oauth is deprecated , thats why I am looking for oauth2. Any Idea if we can use any java library?

Comment: I just noticed this one - isn't this oAuth2? https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/oauth2  - wait, I'm coming back to this after a few days. You want to implimented the authorization side of oauth2 not just authenticate. right?

Comment: @MarkAKruger, that's the one i shared in my answer and it does not contain all functionalities of OAuth2 protocol according to OP. I really haven't got time to validate his point. But from the mere glance at CFC, he seems correct.

Comment: sorry to reconfuse the issue!!

Comment: @MarkAKruger, no worries. We know you are trying to help. I am glad that it ( not having CF implementation of OAuth2 protocol )is bugging you as much as it is to me. :)